# mobile device back button jquery mobile bug page not styled

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

when I'm using my phone to test the app, I use the back device button to show the previous page this is working with all the pages except one page that shows a not styled page when trying to get to the pervious page so there somthing Odd. 
Here a briefe explanation.
there is 3 page #main_menu , #first_map , #second_map
when I'm into the #second_map page it should go to the #first_page when I press back button 
but actually its showing the #main_menu page with not css styling. 
could you plz tell me  what is the problem an how we can fix it thank you in advance .
I provide the source code :
this is the main_page

```
            </div>
            <h2 id="thx_msg" style="margin:0 auto;"></h2>
           <div class="grid2">
                <div class="first" id="search_btn">
                    <div>
                        <img src="images/loupe.jpg"/>
                    <div>
                    </div>Search for a Spot</div>
                </div>
                <div class="second" id="submit_spot_btn">
                    <div>
                        <img src="images/spot.jpg"/>
                    </div>
                    <div>Submit a spot</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <ul style="margin:0 auto;" class="spaced_list" style="widht:280px;" >
                <li><input type="button" data-role="none" value="Account info" class="btn" style="margin:0 auto;" id="main_page_account_info"/></li>
                <li><input type="button" data-role="none" value="Log Out" class="btn" style="margin:0 auto;"id="main_page_log_out"/></li>
            </ul>
     </div>
```

here is the first_map page is named spot_page

```
<div data-role="page" id="spot_page" data-theme="b">
<div data-role="header" style="overflow:hidden;">
    <img class="logo_icon" src="images/logo_icon.png">
</div><!-- header -->
<div class="clear"></div>
<div id="search_form_holder" style="margin:0px 25px" >
    <p class="center" style="font-size:16px;font-weight:bold;">
        Search for a Spot
    </p>
    <ul class="some_space" style="margin:0 auto;
                                        margin-left:auto;
                                        margin-right:auto;
                                        align:center;
                                        text-align:center;
                                        width:280px;">
    <li><input type="text" id="address_zip" class="field black" placeholder="Address/Zip Code"/></li>
    <li id="to"></li>
    <li><input type="button" data-role="none" style="width:200px;margin:15px auto;" id="search_spot_btn" class="btn" value="Search for a Spot"></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="hidden_scroller" style="display:none">
    <select id="distance" name="Within">
            <option value="1">1 Mile</option>
            <option value="3">3 Miles</option>
            <option value="5">5 Miles</option>
            <option value="10">10 Miles</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div><!-- search form -->
<div id="first_map" style="width: 100%;
                            height: 247px;border:1px solid black;margin:0 auto">

</div>
</div><!-- split  view -->
```

and finally the second map here :

```
        <div data-role="page" id="nearby_page">
        <div data-role="header" style="overflow:hidden;">
            <img class="logo_icon" src="images/logo_icon.png">
        </div><!-- header -->
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="second_header">Spots nearby</div>
        <div id="map" style="width: 100%;
                            height: 398px;border:1px solid black;margin:0 auto">

        </div>
    </div>
```

As you can see the pages are separate from each other.
I have a last question could a navigation plugin help to fix the problem like jquery history plugin and thanks for your help.

Comment: Hello I provided the source code for you thank your for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to have your pages on different separate pages. If not these kind of errors will occur. Mostly, you will encounter abnormal navigation error. That is what I have experienced in my experience.

BTW, you should show more of your code for people here to help  you out.

**Update**

PhoneGap and Android's back button do behaves odd. What I have done in my application is disabled the back button and given the soft back button on the top header. Simple `history.back()` will do the magic for back buttons.

You can disable as follows.

```
$(function(){
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
})

// PhoneGap is loaded and it is now safe to call PhoneGap methods
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    // Register the event listener
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
}

// Handle the back button
//
function onBackKeyDown() {
    console.log("Back button pressed but nothing happened");
}
```

Anyway this is my approach. You may choose to be different.

Comment: I provided the source code of the there pages thank you for your help.